# Need to hide failed log in ansible task

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible tasks, am creating a  yml which performs a login operation and if login gets failed, some script need to be called.

```
  - name: Logging Action
    shell: "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh -u xyzyx -p 1234abc"
    register: loginoutput
    ignore_errors: yes
    no_log: True


  - name: Run the cql script to create new user
    shell:  sh create-new-user.cql"
    when: loginoutput|failed
```

for the above one i created taks that works fine.

My question, when performing login operation - it got failed and showing error messages like below...

I dont want to display the log messgaes even not any failed string in logs.

I tried  `no_log: True` , this gives

> **failed**: [127.0.0.1] => {"censored": "results hidden due to no_log parameter", "changed": true, "rc": 1}

I don't want to show failed string in o/p.

Answer (score 31):

You can't. `no_log: True`is the best there is to prevent output.

If it helps, beside `ignore_errors: yes`, there is the `failed_when` option where you can define exactly what makes the task fail. The idea would be to not let the task fail in the first place.

```
- name: Logging Action
  shell: "/usr/local/bin/cqlsh -u xyzyx -p 1234abc"
  register: loginoutput
  failed_when: false
  no_log: True
```

So in this case, the task will never fail (`false`) but you can provide any sophisticated condition which may be based on the output of the task.

Now, the task did not fail, but the return code of `cqlsh` still is `1`, which you can use in the condition of the next task.

```
- name: Run the cql script to create new user
  shell:  sh create-new-user.cql"
  when: loginoutput.rc == 1
```

In theory this should have the same outcome as before, just that the first task is not marked as failed and therefore `no_log: True` should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting failures, I wonder if you can adjust your inventory to just not run these on the expected failed nodes. Check out groups and perhaps you can build a group (on setup a dynamic inventory).

Another strategy would be to do a check for some file or account to exist to identify where this is likely to succeed and then only run the task when that has succeeded.